# Uninstall unplugged USB driver

Tags: usb, drivers, uninstall, lacie

Running WinXP, I have a Lacie USB HD which prevents (by some bug) starting and terminating of applications on my computer when I plug it in, and so I'm not able to uninstall the device driver. How can I reinstall the drivers? Thanks!

Comment: Try [USB Oblivion](http://superuser.com/a/499402/138343) or [USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html).

Comment: @Karan: Thanks, if you suggest UDB Oblivion as an answer I'll mark it as the correct answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[USBOblivion](http://code.google.com/p/usboblivion/) should be able to help in such situations:

> **USBOblivion** is a utility designed to erase all traces of USB-connected drives and CD-ROMs from the registry in Windows 2000, Windows XP, Windows 2003, Windows Vista, Windows 7 32/64-bit versions. The utility has a test mode of operation, i.e. without actually removing data from the registry, and, just in case, creates a .reg-file to undo any changes. There is also a fully automatic mode.

[image: 1]